# "on active service" vs "in active service"

Tags: british-english

In the Wikipedia article on the RAF ["Grand Slam" bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Slam_%28bomb%29) that was used by the RAF in World War II, it is recorded that the bomb was used 42 times:

> "By the end of the war, 42 Grand Slams had been dropped **on active
>   service**."

This caused me to wonder at the usage of "on" in this context.  And then I was reminded of Ian Fleming's 10th James Bond novel, *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*.  Here seems to be a similar usage of "on".  In US English we would use "in" rather than "on", which leads me to believe that a British-English speaker has edited the Wikipedia article in question (or is that "on question"?).  Because I would have written "had been dropped in active service."  And I'm a Yank.

In the article about the bomb, the referenced sentence has the unfortunate suggestion that the bomb was actually dropped on something called "active service".

My question is (at long last), is this usage of "on" in the sentence above correct usage in British English, or did the writer get it wrong?

Comment: I'd use 'in' not 'on'. And I'd edit thus given a chance.

Comment: Yes, this is why I'm asking.  It's an article on a British subject, probably edited by a Brit.  I don't want to step on any toes by insisting upon Yank word usage and spelling when what I am seeing is a perfectly acceptable Brit usage.  And it's "color" not "colour", by the way. See what I mean?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What of *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*. Would you edit that, too?  (Sincere question, not a challenge.)

Comment: Great question! I'd always wondered about Ian Flemming's usage on that one.

Comment: @David: The agent (either sense!) is on active service (eg my late dad during WWII). The bombs were dropped in (the course of) active service.

Comment: @Edwin Interesting. We'd usually say *on active duty for a person.* *In active service* is usually for items.  But, we would say people were *in The Service*.  We even say *in the line of duty.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't bother me whether OP's citation used ***on*** or ***in***, but the evidence from NGrams suggests Brits in general very much favour the former...

[image]

...whereas Americans use both about equally often...

[image]

On reflection, I think I'm more likely to use ***on*** when referring to, for example, an actual soldier posted to a "tour of duty" overseas. And ***in*** when it's more figurative (such as a piece of antiquated office equipment that's still in daily use).

Comment: While this has little impact on the frequent usage of "in" by Americans, I'd be interested to see how many of the "on" usages are excerpts taken horribly out of context (e.g., "... torture methods used on active service members..."). Based on personal experience, I'd say that the AmE convention is to use "in active service", as "active service" is a state of being that is defined by being *in* combat (OP's preferred usage) rather than by traveling, whereas we would say "on" when travel is made explicit by word choice (e.g., "on a tour of duty"; "on a mission"; "on a journey/trip"; etc.).

Comment: @Cmillz: You're welcome to wade through as many of these 5000 instances of ["used on active service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22used+on+active+service%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as you want. I just leafed through the first 2-3 pages and saw no examples of the kind of "false positive" you suggest. I doubt there would be any significant numbers in total, and I've just checked there are definitely none at all if I extend the search string with any of the likely candidates *personnel, soldiers, members*.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps there's a regional factor? Perhaps I'm just in a sort of bubble with that specific usage? I don't know, I just don't recall ever seeing "on" used in that particular situation (not that my own personal anecdotal evidence is really evidence of anything, of course). Perhaps I just haven't noticed it... in any case, +1'd.

Comment: @Cmillz: Before I actually checked the NGrams, I thought it was more likely *Brits* would be more "flexible" than Americans. Of course, there's no way of telling how many speakers always (or usually) stick with one preposition or the other in all contexts - or indeed how many use both forms indiscriminately, as opposed to being context-variable. But in the end the prepositions are arbitrary, and probably easily influenced by association with ***on** duty*, ***in** service*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki article should read "in", not "on". *People* are described as "on" active service, while *things* are described as "in" active service. Thus James Bond is "On" HMSS. I believe this is no different from US usage, where someone might be described as "on" a mission?

Comment: Yes, and that is interesting in that in AE, I might be "on" a mission, but I would be "in" active service.  Hmmm.  At least, "in" would be *my* word choice.

Comment: As I commented on the response of @FumbleFingers, I believe the AmE usage has more to do with viewing "in active service" as a state of being, whereas "a mission" or "a tour of duty" necessitates denotatively (by the definitions of the words mission and tour) that the individual travel – so the same convention is used as in "going *on* a trip".

Answer (score 0):

Why settle for in or on, I think it would be clearer to say *during*

> 42 Grand Slams had been dropped *during* active service

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of "on" here is not strictly correct, but would seem natural to many British people. I believe this is because the phrase "on active service" became very familiar through being used (in the First World War, at least) as a way in which British army soldiers could frank letters by hand (i.e. send them without a postage stamp by writing this phrase on the envelope).

But why did this franking-phrase start with "on" instead of "in"? My guess is that the phrase was created on the model of a frank well known in government business in Britain: "On His[/Her] Majesty's Service". Until recently this was often used for letters from government departments. Ian Fleming was trading on its familiarity when he spiced it with the word "secret" in the title of his novel.

But still there is a puzzle. Why "on" His/Her Majesty's service?
My further guess is that this "on" was originally the "on" of accounting liability, as in "the drinks are on me" or "a tax on windows". So "on His/Her Majesty's Service" might have meant "the cost of sending this letter is accountable to government or interests of state".